# SVN diff shows changes, SVN merge does not

Tags: svn

I've come back to SVN after a number of years and I am trying to get my head around branching / merging.  I have the following test setup on a linux box and I'm using command line:

Project

- trunk
- branch
- tags

I have local working copies of the branch and trunk in ~/workingcopy and ~/workingcopybranch

For test purposes I have imported a SeamTest project.  Both working copies are currently at revision 14. with everything committed back to the repository

Here is the result from my diff:

```
~/workingcopy/SeamTest $ svn diff http://localhost/svn/myproject/branches/heidisbranch/SeamTest http://localhost/svn/myproject/trunk/SeamTest
Index: WebContent/home.xhtml
===================================================================
--- WebContent/home.xhtml   (.../branches/heidisbranch/SeamTest)    (Revision 14)
+++ WebContent/home.xhtml   (.../trunk/SeamTest)    (Revision 14)
@@ -8,7 +8,6 @@
     xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
     template="layout/template.xhtml">
 <!-- testing -->
-<!-- adding info into branch code-->
     <ui:define name="body">

         <h1>Welcome to Seam!</h1>
Index: .
===================================================================
--- .   (.../branches/heidisbranch/SeamTest)    (Revision 14)
+++ .   (.../trunk/SeamTest)    (Revision 14)

Eigenschaftsänderungen: .
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:mergeinfo
```

As you can see the comment "adding info into branch code" is in the branch and the comment "testing" is in the trunk

When I then go to perform SVN merge from the trunk working directory it doesn't seem to register that there are differences:

```
~/workingcopy/SeamTest $ svn merge http://localhost/svn/myproject/branches/heidesbranch/SeamTest http://localhost/svn/myproject/trunk/SeamTest .
-- Zusammenführen der Unterschiede zwischen Projektarchiv-URLs in ».«:
 G   .
--- Eliding mergeinfo from '.':
 U   .
-- Aufzeichnung der Informationen für Zusammenführung zwischen Projektarchiv-URLs in ».«:
 G   .
```

No changes are made to the working copy of my project.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the two arguments, i.e. the following should work in your case:

```
$ svn merge http://localhost/svn/myproject/trunk/SeamTest \
     http://localhost/svn/myproject/branches/heidesbranch/SeamTest .
```

However: You didn't mention what you want to achieve. If you are a SVN beginner, it is really unlikely that you want to do that. There are four different forms of merge operations in SVN:

- sync merges
- cherry-pick merges
- reintegrations
- 2-URL merges

You are using the last one, that is intended only for special cases. You should typically stay with the other forms, that are easier to use. And I strongly recommend reading some documentation about working on feature and release branches in SVN.

Comment: I have written two articles about feature and release branches, which might be interesting to you: [Release Branches](http://www.nosid.org/apache-subversion-release-branches.html) and [Feature Branches](http://www.nosid.org/apache-subversion-feature-branches.html) (in German).

Comment: Thanks - I actually want to reintegrate the changes I made in the branch back into the trunk.  So in the trunk I´d like to see the comment "-<!-- adding info into branch code-->" back in the xhtml file.

Comment: Your article on Feature branches was exactly what I was looking for. I followed that through and it is working perfectly. Many thanks.